# what is the cli command in windows to allow domain user to login?

Tags: authentication, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

In windows Server 2012 R2, i have added the server to a domain.
The domain has accepted this server to be part of the domain.

How to allow the domain administrator to login to this server?

Should i add the domain administrator to local user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an account as a member of the administrators group you need to be a local administrator already and you need to have rights to read the active directory information. A normal user can do this so what you want to do should be possible:

1. log on as local admin
2. connect on the VPN
3. open Start | Computer Management | Local Users and Groups (or run `lusrmgr.msc`)
4. double-click on the 'Administrators' group
5. click the 'Add...' button

At this point, because you are on the VPN and the machine is a member of the domain, you should be able to click on the 'Locations...' button and select the domain as the location of the user list. At some point an authentication dialogue should pop up and you will need to enter your normal domain credentials.